# Can't think of a query structure to normalize this table

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have a table of cities with their respective states.

Currently the states are stored as varchars (state abbreviations), but in order to normalize the table I have a new states table that stores state IDs.

So I added a column in the cities table that I want to populate with the state_id's, matching on the abbreviations stored in states and cities.

Once that's done I can delete the abbreviation column in cities.

For some reason I can't think of a single query to run this ?  would like to avoid making a procedure if possible... I think my creative juice is running out today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  city_state cs
  INNER JOIN state s ON s.StateAbbr = cs.State
SET
  cs.StateID = s.StateID
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this.

```
UPDATE
  city_state cs
SET
  cs.StateID = (Select StateID from state where s.State = cs.StateAbbr);
```

Comment: cs.StateAbbr is not visible inside the sub-query.